# How to create mouse over with clickable links in it

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp

I want to create a mouse over menu which should display sub navigation menu that is clickable.
On `mouseover` over a text it should display another sub menu that has clickable `href` links. Currently when I mouse over it is displaying a sub menu. But I am not able to click since it fades away as soon I come out of menu to sub menu (on `mouseout`).

Comment: <a  onmouseover="mouseOver2()" onmouseout="mouseout2()" href="/abc">MENU 1 </a>                                                                                                 function mouseOver2() {
 
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display='block';
    
}
function mouseout2() {
 
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display='none';
    
}

Comment: Please provide a working example of what have you tried. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) could be an option to do this.

Comment: Also, I would recommend to use an `<ul>` with `<li>` and `<a>` inside that `<li>`

Comment: [Google is your friend.](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20create%20a%20dropdown%20menu)

Answer (score 0):

I always use bootstrap's drop down for this scenario.

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp

Also, if you want to use WordPress, check out this great tutorial on using the Bootstrap drop downs

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-bootstrap-navbar-into-wordpress-theme--wp-33410